# How to apply hair particles preserving thickness

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I am making a towel by having a particle system on a mesh. The particle system is hair with some thickness to create the illusion of a towel threads. Now I would want to convert it to mesh so I can import it to another software, however clicking "convert to mesh" in modifier stack results in hair with no thickness

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible, you need to convert your meshes to curve and give thickness to these curves , then back to mesh if you want meshes